# how do I pass additional props into a react component through a higher order function

Tags: reactjs

I think it's called higher order function, but I'm not sure.

What I'm trying to accomplish is something kind of similiar to redux to get a better understanding of how it works, and looking for a good way of passing additional props into a component.

Heres my code.. https://jsfiddle.net/ncc8nprc/2/

I have all the props that I want inside the constructor, but not in the rest of the class e.g. render method.

And I get an error that says `make sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was passed`. so I understand this is the wrong way of doing it. :P

But how can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a valid React Component from your high order component, it means using the jsx syntax and a Uppercase first letter:

```
    function stateConnector(mapStateToProps) {
        return function(Component) {

            return class Wrap extends Component {
                render() {
                    const combinedProps = { ...this.props, ...AppState};
                    return <Component {...combinedProps}/>;

                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Here is [the working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8xwvja4/).

Comment: Is that how Redux do with the connect function?

Comment: Yes and no: the structure you present here is identical in Redux connect except in the way the component is returnes. [Redux use the React API createElement](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L237).